# For java doc comments how do you properly comment a void method?

Tags: java, javadoc

I know for methods with parameters and constructors, you do @param or @return but how do you reference a void method in java docs?

Comment: A void method is like any other method except that it's without a return. So you simply use the same javadoc conventions as with other methods just with no @return part.

Comment: What do you mean by reference? Do you mean how to document it? You obviously don't need a `@return` in the JavaDoc of a `void` method and you only need `@param` if it takes arguments. Otherwise, just describe what the (observable) effect of calling the method is.

Comment: Have a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#examples

Answer (score 1):

If a method is self descriptive I would avoid doing something like below:

```
/** Does Foo */
 void doFoo();
```

What you may consider is making sure that method names are also factored in, something like :

```
 /**
 * This method currently launches the ball into the air.
 */
void execute() { ... }
```

to

```
void launchBallIntoAir() { ... }
```

Note that the word currently is also used as your method may evolve over time. It may seem a bit obvious but this is the sort of thing I would do if I was being pedantic.